# How to know if an object property exists and has a value

Tags: javascript, object, properties, exists

It happens to me lots of times in javascript, php and other languages.

1. I need to know if an object exists
2. I need to know if that object has a property
3. I need to check if the value of that property meets a condition

I use to do like this :

```
if (typeof myObject != "undefined") {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty('myProp') {
    if (myObject.myProp == "myTestValue") {
      // execute code
    }
  }
}
```

if I do just like this :

```
if (myObject.myProp == "myTestValue") {
  // execute code
}
```

it raises an error if object or property doesn't exist.

Is there a way of doing that with one line of code ?

Tks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator for that

```js
if (myObject?.myProp === "myTestValue") {
  // execute code
}
```